# data not binding to Bootstrap table in cakephp 3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-3.4

I am using cakephp 3.4 and bootstrap 3.3.7 versions.
I am trying to load the bootstrap table with the data from the controller method. My code is

In Controller method:

```
public function test(){
 $data = $this->User->find("all");
 $this->set(array(
        'data' => $leads,
        '_serialize' => array('data')
        )); 
}
```

The ctp file code is:

```
<table id="table-leads" data-toggle="table" data-url="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>test">
 <tbody>                   
 <tr>
 <th data-field="name">Name</th>
 </tr>
 </tbody>                    
 </table>
```

The data returned in console is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "User 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "User 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "User 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is no error returned but the table is not filled with data.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

there is no mention about this attribute inside Bootstrap documentation
Are you sure that you don't use another script like [Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) or something else using for example [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ?